# Insight into 你好

Tags: history

My textbook says that ''until recently, 你好 was only used to greet foreigners, but now even native speakers use it to greet each other.''

Wow, so when was 你好 invented/added to the Chinese lexicon ?

Does the senior demographic in China use it ?

Answer (score 2):

Foreigners? I would say strangers.

We use "你好" or "您好" as a propriety.

To greet someone elder or higher status, we'll say "您好", if greet friends we'll say "嗨、哈囉" same to **hi** and **hello** to be more close, and say "你好" to someone not very familiar(strangers).

And yes, almost everyone use these to greet.

Answer (score 1):

Most people treat 你好 as a formal greeting for example

> 服务员:"你好, 这位先生\女士"
>
> 客服:"你好，尊敬的用户"
>
> 臣民:"你好, 陛下"

As you can see from those examples, when we use 你好, it shows respect, but  feels a distance.

To make it informal, we can use 你好呀, which is also more often used.

Answer (score 0):

你好 could be used to strangers.

consider:

- Call their name or nickname (for your classmates / colleagues / family members same or younger generations) 小张，老李，王明
- Call surname + position  (for your teacher / leader) 赵经理，王主任，孙老师
- Call job occupation (for shop assistant / restaurant waiter / etc.) 服务员，师傅，老板
- Call by family relationship (for family members elder generations) 爸爸，二姑，三舅母
- ....

In case all these not work. You can still use 你好.

<sup><sub>Someone could help me fix these English as it may not be represented correctly.</sub></sup>

Answer (score -4):

你好 is "hi", "hello". And everyone uses it. I don't think it's correct from what you described textbook.

Comment: Why do you not think it's correct ? If you are Chinese then would your grandparents say 你好 to each other ?

Comment: 你好 is an all time, all age, daily used language for Chinese to greet each other.

Comment: Hmm ... It sounds like you are merely basing that on your own personal experience.

Comment: And it's true. https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD/32416?fr=aladdin